# Only Allow Task Assignee to Complete the Task

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, tasks

How can I prevent people other than the task assignee to complete a task?

At the moment, for some reason, anyone is able to complete the task.

I'm ideally looking for a solution that involves the GUI only. If this isn't possible I'd be open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this was possible with item level permissions on the task list. List > Settings > Advanced Settings > Check "Create items and edit items that were created by the user".

But in the end I went the event receiver route because it allowed me to not only allow only the task assignee to edit the task, but also the task assignee's manager and people in a specified SharePoint user group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with the help of JSLink when rendering the task list view. I have done the same thing at my end with the help of SPService jQuery Library.

When view is being rendered, CSR will append some extra script block for particular check box to verify if the logged in user is part of the assignee group or user.

Or as other option you can have custom event receiver on that particular task list and prevent data from saving, if the logged user is not part of the assignee group or user.

Comment: By JSLink do you mean Client Side Rendering? Is your suggestion to hide items in the list that are not assigned to the current user? This would be unsuitable for me because it's not a secure way of preventing users from editing their own tasks. An event receiver is definitely an alternative option, but I would prefer an out of the box solution, if at all possible.

Comment: **Yes**, It was about CSR(Client Side Rendering). This is just an approach. Or else you can come up with event receiver code as an alternative option.